# Accessing Spark.SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark. Following the below example in a book, I found that the command below was giving the error. What would be the best way to run a Spark-SQL command, whilst coding in general in Spark?

```
scala> // Use SQL to create another DataFrame containing the account
summary records
scala> val acSummary = spark.sql("SELECT accNo, sum(tranAmount) as TransTotal FROM trans GROUP BY accNo")
<console>:37: error: not found: value spark
```

I tried importing import org.apache.spark.SparkContext or using the sc object, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're in the spark-shell, then first get a sql context thus:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
```

Then you can do:

```
val acSummary = sqlContext.sql("SELECT accNo, sum(tranAmount) as TransTotal FROM trans GROUP BY accNo")
```

Comment: Thanks, Phasmid. Your tip helped me trace the issue.

Comment: Most relatively recent versions of the shell come with a sqlContext built for you already

Answer (score 0):

So the value `spark` that is available in `spark-shell` is actually an instance of `SparkSession` (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession)

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
```

will give you one.

Comment: Thanks for helping, triggerNZ.

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using? It appears you're in the shell and this should work, but only in Spark 2+ - otherwise you have to use `sqlContext.sql`

Comment: Thanks, Justin. I am using Spark 1.6 and so the above helped.